# Retrieve specific data with XRAY cloud API GraphQL

Tags: api, graphql, postman, test-plan, x-ray

I know the title of the questions its too much generic, but i making my best. Thanks to everyone. SORRY FOR THIS LONG QUESTION MY ENGLISH ITS NO PERFECT I DONT KNOW IF I COULD SHORTEN THE QUESTION :S

So, the first thing.

- I used xray cloud API for making requests.
- I can make the requests with GraphQL
- I use postman for making this requests.

I have no problem with the documentation. This one -> https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/doc/graphql/testplan.doc.html
I can retrieve any data with this.

Now, its a struggle some times to retrieve data which its easyly readeble in JIRA/XRAY WEB but to retrieve the same data with the API its painfull.

I am gonna put two example.
**The FIRST one**
On XRAY/JIRA WEB i can acces to this metrics (goin through 'Testing Board' -> 'Reports' -> 'Test Plan Metrics') as you can see in the image
[image: How to access to TestPlan metrics]

**,Then**
[image: TestPlan metrics]

Finally **just click on 'Generate Report'** and you will se something like this
[image: DATA]
HERE, we can see some data like the 'status', 'total of test executions', 'test runs', 'test', 'defects' and 'test types'.
**I RETRIEVE THIS DATA VÍA XRAYCLOUD API WITH GRAPHQL ON POSTMAN** (following the documentation), like this:

```
query ($issueIdKey: String){

getTestPlan(issueId: $issueIdKey) {
    issueId
    jira(fields: ["key", "summary", "status", "description", "assignee", "reporter"])
    tests(limit:100){
        total
    }
    testExecutions(limit:10){
            total
            results{
                issueId
                jira(fields: ["key", "summary", "status", "description", "assignee", "reporter"])
                testRuns(limit:100){
                    total   
                    results{
                        test{
                            jira(fields: ["key", "summary", "priority", "status"])
                            issueId
                            status{
                                name
                            }
                            testType {
                                name
                            }
                            preconditions(limit: 10) {
                                total
                                results {
                                    jira(fields: ["key", "summary"])
                                }
                            }                         
                        }
                        comment
                        defects
                        status{
                            name
                        }
                        evidence{
                            filename
                        }
                        steps{
                            id
                            action
                            data
                            result
                            attachments {
                                filename
                            }
                            defects
                            evidence{
                                filename
                            }
                            comment
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

}

THERE ITS ANYWAY to EXTRACT THE DATA WE HAVE SEEN ON THE IMAGE WITHOUT GOING THROUGH ALL THIS REQUEST? (ON THE REQUEST i have to navigate through the TestExecutions, then through testRuns and finally throug test of the TestRun)
According to the documentation i **CANT** get the 'DEFECTS' of the TestPlan (nor the TEST).

**So, this its the thing, THERE ITS ANYWAY TO EXTRACT ALL THIS DATA EASLY AS FOR EXMAPLE PROPERTIES OF THE TESTPLAN?**

**And THE SECOND one its not a big deal as the first one. But if you have something to say about i would love to hear it.**
Example 1:

On XRAY/JIRA WEB i have this data for example
[image]

As you can see i have the execution result of the TestPlan (which its the total result execution of all de TestCases)

My wonder here it is, there is any way i can reatry this execution result of the TestPlan **easyly** with the Xray Cloud Api using GraphQL? Because for me, if i want to retrieve the execution result of the TestPlan i have to retrieve **ALL TEST** and see the result of each one.

**In general. There it is anyway to extract data (or properties) of the TESTPLAN without going through ALL TEST (or TEST EXECUTION or TEST RUNS)?
Thank you, i would appreciate any response to my question!**